# ¿Como hago uso del modulo mysql de node desde ionic 2?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Necesito conectarme con una base de datos usando el modulo mysql de node_modules, usando el marco de ionic 2, en proyectos anteriores donde trabaje solo con express lo hacia facilmente, pero con ionic 2 no se como integrar estos, lo que he logrado encontrar en internet lo hacen de esta forma, pero la palabra clave `require` no la reconoce y por lo tanto no encuentra el modulo.

```
modulos.import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
var mySQLLibreria = require('mysql');

/*
  Generated class for the ServicioMySQL provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ServicioMySQL {
    mySQL; 


  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServicioMySQL Provider');
    this.mySQL= mySQLLibreria;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás confundiendo conceptos, si no es así esque no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer.

Te explico un poco como lo veo yo:

Ionic se usa para crear apps móviles que pueden o no tener una BD propia en el teléfono, para esto usa Bases de datos SQLite y puedes acceder a ellas con el plugin sqlite, mas info [aquí](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/)

Si lo que quieres es conectarte a una BD Mysql que se ejecuta en un servidor de internet, tendrás que hacerlo mediante llamadas HTTP a una API.

Comment: Lo que dice tiene razón, pero al trabajar con la tecnología de ionic para el desarrollo de app móviles, al mismo tiempo estas creando una web, aun que este no es el punto, mi duda es como puedo yo hacer uso de los modulos de node que se encuentra en la carpeta node_modules al momento de crear un proyecto con el comando de ionic start myApp. como inyecto estos modulos a mi app, he visto una solucion por internet y hacen esto:

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
var mySQLLibreria = require('mysql');


@Injectable()
export class ServicioMySQL {
 mySQL; 


  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServicioMySQL Provider');
    this.mySQL= mySQLLibreria;
  }

}

Comment: Pero al hacer eso mismo no funciona por que no reconoce la palabra clave require y por lo tanto no encuentre el modulo.

Comment: ¿Puedes pasarme el enlace a la web la que explican eso para que lo revise?
Hasta donde yo sé, no se puede hacer lo que quieres, para conectarte a una BD mysql externa desde Ionic tienes que hacer peticiones HTTP y que te devuelvan datos en XML o JSON